# Form of Shiva to visualise during chanting

Tags: shiva, mantras, shaivism

I am searching for references to understand iconography of lord Shiva that we can visualise during *om Namah Shivaya* chanting.

Comment: Every mantra chanting have a Dhayna sloka/mantra associated with it .. while chanting one can visualize that form described by that particular Dhyana sloka.

Comment: What’s the dhaya sloka/mantra for the shiva 5 letter mantra? @Rickross

Comment: You can get the Dhyana sloka form here (https://www.scribd.com/doc/294502687/82534177-Shiva-Panchakshari-Mantra-Sadhana) ..it begins with Om Dhyaye nityam Mahesham ...

Comment: Thanks @Rickross, I saw few more things mentioned in the document.  Seems like a master doc for this mantra. Is it given by some guru or collected form some scripture?

Comment: Those are the usual and general steps for a complete mantra japa ritual ..all these steps are from one scripture or the other.